Using PHP to check if there are unsuitable characters in a textarea form
The $handle is given the value of '1' even if there are no characters in the text area which appear in the array.

$handle = '';
$message 'nothing in here except plain text';


        // check message doesnt contain odd characters
        $check = 'href,http,#,¥,²,æ,é,Hello. And Bye.,£,$,ˆ,ª,³,¦,½,å,œ,…,§,¾,‡,»,ç,º,³,ä,¿,Â,¶,¸,µ,Ž,°,Œ,Å,’,€,â,¢,¬,ƒ,Æ,†,±,š,¡,Ñ,‘,Ë,‹,¹,·,Þ,`';
        
        $check = explode(",", $check);

        $num = count($check);
        
        $num = $num + 1;
        
        $count = 0;

        while ($count < $num) {
            
            if (strpos($message,$check[$count]) !== false) {
            $handle = 1; break;
            }
            
            $count++;
        }


(1)Remove the line $num = $num + 1; please (this line doesn't make sense in your code) . (2) On the other hand, you are missing = in the line $message  'nothing in here except plain text'; you posted, it should be $message ='nothing in here except plain text';

What is in your $check array when you display it for debugging purposes? Anything you're not expecting? When I copy your code to a test site, it leaves $handle as an empty string.

@ken,, are you the stack exchange examiner board or something? see the voted answer if you want to know how its done

@tard, if you carefully read my comments, you should know what is/are wrong with your original code, and actually in my opinion such a question should be regarded as due to typos / unreproducible instead of to be "answered" (By the way, to be frank I do not need to view the voted answer to know how it is done /or should be done in a proper way)

@ken,, LOL! Cheers for making me laugh Ken, I needed that

Here is the improved, bug-free version of your code.
Bugs

In $message, the = sign is missing between $message and string 'nothing in here except plain text'.

$handle is set as an empty string (''), but it’s better to use 0 or boolean false.

Adding 1 to $num was unnecessary and could cause an error.

The original code was a bit confusing. It can be improved for clarity and better flow.


Improvements:

Removal of Unnecessary Calculations: Removed $num and $count variables for simplicity.
Use of foreach Loop: This is more readable than a while loop and eliminates the need for a counter.
Variable Naming: Improved readability with clear variable names ($checkChars and $checkArray).

<?php
    $handle = 0;
    $message = 'nothing in here except plain text href';
    
    // Check message doesn't contain odd characters
    $checkChars = 'href,http,#,¥,²,æ,é,Hello. And Bye.,£,$,ˆ,ª,³,¦,½,å,œ,…,§,¾,‡,»,ç,º,³,ä,¿,Â,¶,¸,µ,Ž,°,Œ,Å,’,€,â,¢,¬,ƒ,Æ,†,±,š,¡,Ñ,‘,Ë,‹,¹,·,Þ,`';
    $checkArray = explode(",", $checkChars);
    
    foreach ($checkArray as $char) {
        if (strpos($message, $char) !== false) {
            $handle = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    echo $handle;

Online Demo

Thank you Hassaan!!! I'm just getting to grips with php here, appreciate you taking the time

Your answer highlights some enhancements, but it would be much more useful if it also explained what exactly the bug was in the original code.

There really are some plumbs on SE aren't there? Thanks again Hassan, it was perfect!!

@ÁlvaroGonzález I’ve updated my answer to include an explanation of the errors

Thank you, @tard! I'm glad I could help
